# How to check if column of NumPy array contains specific string?

Tags: python, numpy

Let's assume I have an NumPy array:

```
contacts = np.array([
    ["Apples","Burger"],
    ["Bananas","Cake"],
    ["Grapes","Honey"]
])
```

Now, I want to find at which position "Banana" is and clear the entire column, so the array turns into this:

```
contacts = np.array([
    ["Burger"],
    ["Cake"],
    ["Honey"]
])
```

How can I do this with code?

Comment: With code, which your question appears to be lacking.

Comment: What if there are multiple columns that contain your search term?

Comment: @roganjosh If duplicates in count, then the first triggered will be deleted. But this wasnt the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
contacts[:,(contacts == 'Bananas').sum(0) == 0]

array([['Burger'],
       ['Cake'],
       ['Honey']], dtype='<U7')
```

Answer (score 1):

A combination of `where` and `delete` should do what you want.

```
contacts = np.array([
    ["Apples","Burger"],
    ["Bananas","Cake"],
    ["Grapes","Honey"]
])
row,col = np.where(contacts == "Bananas")
new_contacts = np.delete(contacts,col, axis=1)
```

Where it locates the element and returns the position in both axes (look up what it does in case of multiple matches to avoid surprises). Delete removes a complete sub-array of `contacts` at the position and axis specified.

Answer (score 1):

The where() method generates the X,Y location of the target position. You want to delete the column, thus should use the Y coordinate. Use delete() method to delete the column(casted to integer) on the first axis to delete from (and cause of concurrency you should cast the output result of the command and override the main object, only then print it):

```
contacts = np.delete(contacts, int(np.where(contacts == "Bananas")[1]), 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check for *inequality* and then only take the columns where `all` the values of the test are `True` (i.e. the columns where none of the values are `"Bananas"`).

```py
contacts = contacts[:, (contacts != "Bananas").all(0)]
```